# How can I test LinkedNotebooks in the Evernote Sandbox?

Tags: evernote, evernote-app-notebook

I want to write an evernote integration for a webservice with read-only access to only one notebook per user. The only way to do this seems to create a user where the webservice has full access and then the users share their one notebook with that user.
I wanted to test that functionality in the sandbox but when I go to the page for the notebook the "share" button disappears as soon as the page is fully loaded in about 90% of tries. If the button actually appears and I try to share the notebook I get an error message that the chat message could not be sent.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Facing the same problem, only now the button is simply disabled. Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: No, I am no longer using or developing applications for evernote. I am too annoyed with the user experience, the documentation and the (lack of) support.